# Sparkpost disable engangement tracking

Tags: civimail, sparkpost

Has anyone successfully switched off Engagement Tracking on SparkPost?

I did this at https://app.sparkpost.com/account/smtp

But all links are getting converted to http://go.sparkpostmail.com/

Answer (score 0):

'options' => [
    'sandbox' => false,
    "open_tracking" => false,
    "click_tracking" => false
  ],

Comment: Thanks for providing your answer. Can you please provide some more instructions and an explanation of what this line of code means, where it goes, and why it helps?